# What is CPU_DABORT_HANDLER used for in glue-df.h?

Tags: assembly, exception, linux-kernel, arm

In the Linux kernel there is this file that is part of the ARM data abort exception handling code that undefines CPU_DABORT_HANDLER, then checks to see if it is defined further down.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/112cbae26d18e75098d95cc234cfa5059de8d479/arch/arm/include/asm/glue-df.h#L31

Why is this code there? How would you use it?

Comment: The macro CPU_DABORT_HANDLER is defined as one of several different symbols depending on what CONFIG_CPU_ABRT_* configuration macros have been defined. If more than one of these configuration macros is defined then MULTI_DABORT is defined as 1. The header exists to determine which style of data abort handler the kernel should use, and you shouldn't need to use it for anything except for building the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

> In the Linux kernel there is this file that is part of the ARM data abort exception handling code that undefines CPU_DABORT_HANDLER, then checks to see if it is defined further down.

...

> Why is this code there?

There are two cases that this is handling.  One is a custom kernel build for a specific CPU.  The second if for a Linux kernel that can run on multiple boards (Debian, Ubuntu, etc).  You need to examine the other peices of the puzzle.

- [entry-armv.S](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/112cbae26d18e75098d95cc234cfa5059de8d479/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S#L64)
- [asm-offsets.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/112cbae26d18e75098d95cc234cfa5059de8d479/arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.c#L153)

The important section is in entry-armv.S macro `dabt_helper`.

```
        .macro  dabt_helper

        @
        @ Call the processor-specific abort handler:
        @
        @  r2 - pt_regs
        @  r4 - aborted context pc
        @  r5 - aborted context psr
        @
        @ The abort handler must return the aborted address in r0, and
        @ the fault status register in r1.  r9 must be preserved.
        @
#ifdef MULTI_DABORT
        ldr     ip, .LCprocfns
        mov     lr, pc
        ldr     pc, [ip, #PROCESSOR_DABT_FUNC]
#else
        bl      CPU_DABORT_HANDLER
#endif
        .endm
```

The generic code will call `dabt_helper`.  This is either a direct function call for the CPU specific build.  Otherwise it is a function pointer lookup (which can be difficult for a CPU to pre-fetch) being slightly slower and more code.

> How would you use it?

You use it with kernel 'kconfig' options.  If you compile for a very specific CPU, then you will get the direct function call.

Comment: `PROCESSOR_DABT_FUNC` is an entry in the 'processor' structure which is dynamically IDed by the init code before Linux loads any processes.  Linux selects the right 'processor' based on CP15 registers (or possibly other info for errata devices).  The offset in the structure is found by compiling a dummy program to assembler and then text processing the assembler for an offset.  When you compile for a specific CPU, then none of this needs to happen.  The kernel may ID the CPU and abort in init if the CPU doesn't match.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the usage, but the first #ifdef CPU_DABORT_HANDLER will be preprocessed away to nothing 100% of the time
`#undef CPU_DABORT_HANDLER
#undef MULTI_DABORT

#ifdef CONFIG_CPU_ABRT_EV4</br>
# ifdef CPU_DABORT_HANDLER
#  define MULTI_DABORT 1
# else
#  define CPU_DABORT_HANDLER v4_early_abort
# endif
#endif`

Comment: Yes, but what happens if both `CONFIG_CPU_ABRT_EV5T` and `CONFIG_CPU_ABRT_EV4` are defined?  The very first one doesn't need the '#ifdef CPU_DABORT_HANDLER' because that will never happen, but subsequent ones it will.  This is basic 'C' pre-processor?  I must have given you too much information.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in the question. You confirmed my analysis by your response: 'The very first one doesn't need the #ifdef CPU_DABORT_HANDLER...'.  If the first one doesn't need the ifdef: why is it there?

Comment: Please give greater thought to your tags.  If it is purely on the C pre-processor, then why tag with exception handling?  The 'reasons' are obviously nebulous.  It is not documented by a comment and you would have to research if you really wanted to know.  However since everything is the same if makes the stanza broken by new lines seem similar.  Also, if someone reformats the code and/or adds 'ARMv3' support then it won't break.  **How would you use it?**  Doesn't sound like a style question to me?